# Searching for a range within a comma-separated field

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a field called 'fits' that contains comma separated values like this:

> 120102199105199205,130101199105199205,120101199107199201

where for each number the first 6 digits are a fitment code and the last 12 digits are a unique date range.

Now, I know that CSV is nasty and violates 1NF, but the alternative is normalizing the data into a couple more tables that would be monstrous because of the potential number of records

So in an effort to keep it simple I'm trying to write a query to select rows based on providing the fitment code and a range of dates.  So far I have this:

```
select data from table
where fits = any(
    SELECT fits
    FROM table
    WHERE fits LIKE '120102')
AND fits BETWEEN "120102199105000000" AND "120102999999199205"
```

The problem is, the BETWEEN...AND doesn't work with the CSV data

Is there a way to apply a range in the query with some kind of wildcard to this type of CSV data, or is the only sql-side solution to normalize?

Comment: Obviously your best solution is to generate a reasonable schema, separating the data into columns of fit,date1,date2 and adding rows for each tuple.   Saying that generates "too many records" is a silly reason not to do it.

Comment: You could generate a derived table from the matching records found with this:  CONCAT(,',,fits,',')  LIKE ',120102%' but it would not be completely general

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use BETWEEN for values in your fits column you will need to normalise the data.

This should not necessarily be a problem. How big is the potential row size?  You'd be surprised how many records is not a problem for a modern database server.

1 Million, 10 Million, 100 million really not a problem for any RDMS mysql, mariadb, mssql, postgresSQL on a modern pc.

Normalise your data and everything will be much easier.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I bit the bullet and normalized it.